# Notepad++: Force file/UI tabs to certain width regardless of filename length?

Tags: notepad++, tabs

Is there a way to force tabs to identical size, regardless of filename length?

Here you can see that the size changes entirely depending on the filename length and also position in a multiline config, eg. in_server.txt.
[image]

And related to that, is there also a way to force the multiline tab (files "in_server.txt" and "new 9" in the above example) to the same even width as the files in the second tab row? I've only ever seen the below type of multiline tab which always fills the full row - also regardless of the actual filename length - in any program. Is it a technical limitation of Windows?

`\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml` doesn't have any fitting settings.

Comment: Notepad++ informations about the tab bar: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Tab_Bar

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can currently do is to use **Document Switcher** instead of tabs:

[image]

Filenames there are displayed on area which has **fixed width** so this is close to what you request. You can adjust the width as you wish.

You can set it up in menu Settings > Preferences and also disable the tabs which are no longer needed:

[image]

---

Regarding tab width of **tab control**, maybe you can download and check [Notepad++ source code](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) to see flags used to initialize the tab control. This can give you an answer whether the feature is present for this tab control or not. You can also play with its flags (I remember tab control has one for constant width of its tabs) and create your own build of Notepad++ which will have this feature. Or [submit a feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) for that.